# Handling -uNUM as a bash option

Tags: bash

I have a bash function that handles a usage option for the following situations

```
-u, -u NUM, -u=NUM, -uNUM
```

`nmafr` in a function that tests whether the argument is a numeric whole number.

I could change the `("-u"*)` part, in a way that it handles the case of `-u` followed by at least one alphanumeric character, so that the case of `"-u"` is handled by `("-u"|"--usage")`.

What would be the pattern to use instead of the current `("-u"*)` ?

```
local AFFNUM="nmafr -q -W"

while (( $# > 0 )); do
 case $1 in

  ("-u"|"--usage")
      ## Handle -u NUM, -u allows optional argument value
      if { $AFFNUM "$2"; }; then
        usg="$2" ; shift ; shift
      else
        usg=1 ; shift 1
      fi
      lampi-usage "$usg"
      return 0
      ;;

  ("-u="*|"--usage="*)  
      ## Handle "-u=2", "-u=" allows optional argument value
      if { $AFFNUM "${1#*=}"; }; then
        usg="${1#*=}" ; shift 1
      else
        usg=1 ; shift 1
      fi
      lampi-usage "$usg"
      return 0
      ;;

  ("-u"*)          
      ## Handle -uNUM
      if { $AFFNUM "${1#*-u}"; }; then
        usg="${1#*-u}" ; shift 1
      else
        shift 1
        lferr+=(" {-uNUM} NUM fails numeric validation")
      fi
      lampi-usage "$usg"
      return 0
      ;;

  ("--") shift 1 ; break ;;
  (*) opt_error=1 ; break ;;

 esac
done
```

Comment: Why are you having trouble deciding? You haven't really expressed a problem that can be solved. Is your current code broken in some way, and if so how? Provide example inputs, their wrong outputs, and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

One major issue in your script is that **for all** the case statement branches, you **must** change all instances of

```
( {match1}|{match2}|{match3} ) action1 ;;
```

to

```
{match1} | {match2} | {match3} ) action1 ;;
```

**removing** the open round-bracket on each one.  Otherwise, the **()** pair is considered a sub-shell.

Also, putting **space** between each pattern and the vertical bar, to ensure it is not interpreted as part of the string by being adjacent.

Comment: I don't think either of these assertions are correct. The shell case statement does allow an opening parens as part of the syntax, (sometimes they are very convenient) AND you would only put spaces before/after a `|` (OR) operator if you expect your variable input for case matching includes a space. Unfortunately [Posix Shell Definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) does show spaces before/after the `|` char. (Search for *Case Conditional Construct*).  ,.,,,

Comment: But note that a quick test `arg=a ; case $arg in ( 1|b|a|5 ) echo $arg ;; *) echo no match $arg ;; esac` (returns `a`)  ,,,,doesn't required spaces.

Comment: And `arg=" c d" ; case $arg in (1|b|a|5|\ c\ d) echo $arg ;; *) echo no match $arg ;; esac` returns `c d` (with leading space), while arg=" c d" ; case $arg in (1|b|a|5|c\ d) echo $arg ;; *) echo no match $arg ;; esac` returns `no match  c d` . Good luck to all!

Comment: I go with what I consider the most portable (ash compatible), most of the time.  I only use bash when specific features available in bash dictate its use.

Comment: Did my code samples fail in `ash`? (I would be suprised). But thanks for the feedback. Also I notice that this Q is tagged only with `bash`.